# Capture ajax requests from another tab from another domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser, tabs, csrf

Let's say there is a website on first tab in the browser which communicate with ajax calls to the server.
On the other tab a different site is opened with a different domain this second webpage on the second tab assume it's malicious. Is it possible for that second tab to capture the ajax calls which are triggered on the first tab? Cookies are exclusive for domain so can't temper that from another tab from another domain but can ajax calls be hijacked that way?

Comment: Same Origin Policy

Comment: let's assume CORS added properly

Comment: cors has nothing to do with two tabs

Comment: So it's possible you say but Same Origin Policy prevent this, right? Have an article about it which explains    how it protects this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy